# How to set a Facebook Instant Game leaderbord as contextual using the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-instant-games

I'm making a Facebook Instant Game, I'm using [the graph API to create the leaderboards](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/leaderboards_create/) but I would like to specify them as **contextual** [like it's possible with the interface](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/guides/using-leaderboards/).

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Hi Nomis, and welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Comment: Hello @eduardo, actually my code works.I'm looking for a way to create a leaderboard and specify it as contextual.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create a contextual leaderboard with the API, but only one by one, by calling the leaderboard creation endpoint for each context ID. The Graph API hasn't been a large focus for Instant Games since the platform can be, if needed, client side only, so this is unlikely to change in the near future.

Comment: Ok, so I have to use the JS SDK in the Instant Game to create the leaderboard ?
Too bad we can't setup the leaderboard as contextual like in the interface.

Comment: Why do you want to be able to do this?

Comment: because I'm generating different quizes and I want to have a leaderboard for each quiz.
I don't want to create them manualy, but it seems it's the only way to set a leaderboard as contextual. 
So, my idea is to create the leaderboard with the context ID when a quiz is started. If possible.
Not sure If I'm clear.